# internal corrosion of copper pipe from various causes and tools, prep, and procedures required to prevent it

Tags: plumbing, tools, powertools, copper, hand-tools

This is [an interesting video on copper pipe corrosion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nD5lMITzx_Y) from various causes. I am looking for an internal wall deburring tool to prevent the turbulence corrosion. The hand-tools (barrel-shaped) have given me tendonitis and the one with the little blade on the end, whose handle is about the size of a Robusto cigar, leaves lots of scratches on the interior wall of the pipe unless I take great care when paring the burr.  Next stop is to try a conical grit-style grinding bit but I was wondering if there is a standard toolkit that (truly) professional plumbers use, the ones working in localities that demand that these burrs be removed?

Comment: I've always used the one on the end of the tubing cutter.  It doesn't so much remove the burr as bend smooth the end of the pipe so that it is less curved, and thus produces dramatically less turbulence.  It isn't sharp -- the mechanism is that a hard steel v shape will bend the much softer copper back into the correct position.

Comment: Corrosion is a function of the fluid in the pipe ; there is very little affect of turbulence/velocity.

Comment: The video shows an example of the corrosion caused by turbulence/velocity, though it does seem the contents of the fluid (iron, flux) have far worse effects.

Comment: I use both the swivel deburring tool I think this is your cigar type on large pipe and the inside outside cone under 1” the cone result looks better and when assembling swaged prices of copper you need to deburr the outside of the inner pipe plus abrasive cloth to expose fresh copper. I agree with blacksmith that turbulence is not a major factor compared to the chemicals in the water or total lack of ions both can etch pipes on the inside , on the outside something as simple as a galvanized strap or touching another metal will cause leaks , not having dielectric unions at transitions to steel

Comment: Watching the video of a plumber pretending to be a metallurgist was interesting ; basically they have aggressive water and under deposit corrosion. Unless you have some reason to suspect you have aggressive/corrosive water, I would not do anything out of the ordinary based on the video. I had one house where the original owner put in a softener and ran it at maximum. After 20 years , I fount two tiny pit leaks in copper pipe when I moved in caused by the combination of vey soft water and sodium ( from the softener). It seems counterintuitive but soft water can be corrosive ( no calcium scale).

Comment: They had a laboratory analyze the pipe and the analysis revealed iron pitting on the inside of the pipe.  Where did the iron come from? they asked.  Was it in the water? No other neighbors reported such problems.  Did it have another cause?  The plumber deduced that it did, since the hot water heater failed and it was badly rusted inside.  But I am not a forensic metallurgist.  My  question is whether there is something other than the bladed reamers that can be used to deburr.

Comment: They more or less stated the the iron ( oxide)  deposits came from the water heater after the magnesium anode was consumed and no longer protected the steel tank. Iron oxide scales were carried in the hot water and deposited in the bottom of straight horizontal pipe runs.

Comment: Yes, the lab found the iron corrosion in the pipe under microscopic examination of the pitting but the lab did not explain how the iron got there. It was the plumber who deduced it had come from the rusty direct hot water heater. But I don't recall if they analyzed the mains water for high levels of iron, though I do remember them mentioning that the problem was not happening throughout the neighborhood and concluding tentatively from that fact that the water supply was probably within normal range for iron.